# Can I create this line in css?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I don't want to use many svg files for this green line. can I make this with like border-left or something ?

[image]

```html
<Image src={greensvg} />
              <p>
                A minimum of 5 years designing experiences and products in a
                professional setting.
              </p>

<Image src={greensvg} />
              <p>
                A minimum of 5 years designing experiences and products in a
                professional setting.
              </p>

<Image src={greensvg} />
              <p>
                A minimum of 5 years designing experiences and products in a
                professional setting.
              </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
p {
  padding-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

p:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  A minimum of 5 years designing experiences <br />and products in a professional setting.
</p>
```

Try out if this works for you, you can play with the width of the element in this way.

Answer (score 2):

You can have indented list effect with pseudo class `:before`.
Something like this:

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
}

ul.dashed {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul.dashed>li:before {
  content: "-";
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="dashed">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: I'd suggest using the `::marker` pseudo-element instead of the generic `::before` (and while `:before` is valid, for legacy reasons, all other pseudo-elements *must* use double-colon notation): https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hoyLspxa/

Comment: thanks but I put width into :before but didn't work. line needs more with. :/ . "-" is just too small.

Comment: You can also change e.g. font-size: 25px and play with font-weight to change dash style.